# Create columned text reStructuredText

Tags: css, restructuredtext

I'm trying to format a reStructuredText section to look like so:

```
type1 : this     type4 : this     type7 : this
type2 : this     type5 : this     type8 : this
type3 : this     type6 : this     type9 : this
```

such that I can fill the page horizontally with text, does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I would guess it would have something to do with css and container?

Comment: Can you post your tried HTML and CSS?

Comment: If using a CSS framework is an option, you could accomplish something like this with Bootstrap.

Comment: Would a table be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best alternative I have, in place of playing with css and container...

I don't think there is a way to natively do what you're trying in restructured text. But, if you use [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/), there is a directive called `hlist` (horizontal list): http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/para.html

You write something like this:

```
.. hlist::
  :columns: 3

* A list of
* short items
* that should be
* displayed
* horizontally
```

And it gets converted to:

[image]

Hope this helps!